# What does `path %path:"=%` do in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, syntax

I found this code in a batch file, but I can't figure out what it does.

`path %path:"=%`

Obviously, it has something to do with setting the system PATH environment variable, but I don't understand why there is syntax inside the %variableName%.  I don't even understand why it doesn't result in a syntax error like `path %path:=%` does.

I looked through the complete batch grammar definition at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting , but I still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: If you want to see the mechanism in its simplest form, create a variable like this, `Set "Var=abc"`, now try this: `Echo %Var%`, then try this: `Echo %Var:a=n%`. Now that you've seen it in action, try: `Echo %Var:b=%`. See if you can then tell us what it's doing.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `set/?` and read the output help carefully and completely from top of first to bottom of last page. It explains the string substitution syntax used here to replace all `"` by an empty string and so remove all `"` from string value of environment variable `PATH` to redefine with __command__ `path` the environment variable `PATH`. Better would be `set "PATH=%PATH:"=%"` because of `path %path:"=%` results in wrong behavior if the value of environment variable `PATH` contains a folder path with `&`.

Comment: `set "PATH=%PATH:"=%"` would be wrong if the list of folder paths assigned to environment variable `PATH` contains a folder path with `;` because of in this case the folder path with the semicolon __must__ be enclosed in `"` to get the semicolon interpreted as literal character and not as separator between the folder paths. See the Wikipedia article about [comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) whereby `PATH` uses `;` instead of `,` as separator.

Answer (score 0):

The `%Variable:x=y%` syntax is substring processing, and replaces all instances of `x` in the string variable with `y`; (or removes `x` if `y` was not given).

`path %path:"=%` removes all quotation marks from the system path.

(Thank you Compo.)

Comment: Now for the advice, never add to, remove from, or modify anything in the system variable `%Path%`

Comment: That's interesting.  Why?  I've frequently seen the path being modified, and I had always understood it to be safe because it only affects the current shell and child processes, and only `setx` is permanent.  Is that untrue?

Comment: Because it is only ever modified by lazy applications and lazy code. It is an important system variable, which should not be changed globally, and rarely modified locally. I have never mofdified mine at any time, and I've been using batch files for over 30 years. Let's take a quick example of common usage. `Set "Path=%Path%;C:\MyExeDirectory"`, then `Start "" "MyApp.exe"`. You can do the same thing like this `Set "MyApp=C:\MyExeDirectory\MyApp.exe"`, then `Start "" "%MyApp%"`. This way there's no possibility whatsoever of making a mistake, and preventing built-in system utilities etc. working.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I agree.  The script is calling a 2nd (very complex) script that makes unhelpful assumptions about the environment.  I don't think the the author of the 1st script had SCM write-access to modify the 2nd script (and neither do I).  I suppose bad practice begets bad practice.

Comment: If you take a look at the vast majority of my answers on this site, you'll note that because the ```%Path%``` variable is abused so often, I always prepend the standard system utility paths with ```%__AppDir__%``` or ```%SystemRoot%\System32\``` to ensure that my code will still work on their corrupted systems. If you take a look at the question posted just after this, you'll see a prime example of how that variable is corrupted.